# Updates in Drupal failed, now stuck in maintenance mode

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, updates, maintenance-mode

I logged in to the company's Drupal (7.19) site and noticed a lot of recommended updates.

```
There is a security update available for your version of Drupal. To ensure the security of your server, you should update immediately! 
See the available updates page for more information and to install your missing updates.
There are security updates available for one or more of your modules or themes. To ensure the security of your server, you should update immediately! 
See the available updates page for more information and to install your missing updates.
```

I chose to download the updates. I then proceeded to update, Drupal suggested I'd do this in maintenance mode. 
Upon proceeding I was greeted by a long message, telling me that all updates had failed because the directories could not be removed.

```
nodeaccesskeys

Error installing / updating
File Transfer failed, reason: Cannot remove directory 

Your modules have been downloaded and updated.
Run database updates
```

When visiting:

```
admin/config/development/maintenance
```

the box that says “Put site into maintenance mode” is not checked, yet the site still remains in maintenance mode when I visit it in another browser (so that I’m not viewing it while being logged in as the administrator.)

I feel both things are related seeing as I had no issues before I tried to update  the modules in question.

I'm not entirely sure what to do here. Is there a way to fix this preferably without resorting to code? I'm not too familiar with Drupal. I just wanted to update out of date modules.

At this point I don't really care about not being able to update, I'd just like the site to not be in maintenance mode anymore.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to clear the cache on /admin/config/development/performance